# Getting errors using routing function in QGIS OSM Tools plugin

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, routing, qgis-3, osmtools

I thought I found just the right tool for creating routes from all points in one layer to all points in another layer: The "Routing" function in [OSM Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMtools/). Unfortunately I am receiving errors trying to execute it.

I am getting the following messages:
`INFO: "Limit exceeded : Request limit of 40 per minute exceeded. Wait for 0.003889799118041992 seconds"` like ten times.

Then there is the Python warning:

```
traceback:
warning:sys:1: ResourceWarning:
unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=4060, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.20.91.24', 8643), raddr=('129.206.7.231', 443)>
```

And the Python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\OSMtools\osm_tools.py", line 145, in run
                route.directions_calc()
              File "C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\OSMtools\directions.py", line 137, in directions_calc
                layer_out = self._addLine(responses, values_list)
              File "C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\OSMtools\directions.py", line 183, in _addLine
                values_list[i][0],
            IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas what could be the problem(s)?

Operating System is Windows 10, x64
QGIS 3.0.0.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem @ThinWhiteDuke?

Answer (score 1):

The Free plans limit to 40 requests per minute and you are exceeding the limit. The [website](https://openrouteservice.org/plans/) lists out.

Free Plan

- 2.500 Requests per day
- up to 40 Requests per minute
- Directions API
- Geocoding API
- Matrix API
- Isochrones API
- POIs API

Most services have such limits on free plans.  You will need to read the documentation or contact the plugin manager for support on this.